# How to you insert a confluence macro into a page created by the Confluence Rest Api? Or how to create a page with macro Attachment?

Tags: rest, confluence

Confluence 6.15.2

I need to insert a macro into an existing page using the REST API.

```html
curl -s -u user:pasw -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     '-d{"id":"246341155",
         "type":"page",
         "space":{"key":"TST"},
         "body":{"value":"<ac:structured-macro ac:name="attachments"><ac:parameter ac:name="old">false</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="sortBy">name</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="upload">true</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>","representation":"storage"}}' 
     https://localhost:8080/rest/api/content/
```

The response:

```html
{"statusCode":500,"message":"","reason":"Internal Server Error"}
```

When creating a page with a macro, the same error occurs, the page is not created:

```html
curl -s -u user:pasw -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' 
     '-d{"type":"page",
         "ancestors":[{"id":246324831}], 
         "title":"New Page",
         "space":{"key":"TST"}, 
         "body":{"storage":{"value":"<ac:structured-macro ac:name="attachments"><ac:parameter ac:name="old">false</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="sortBy">name</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name="upload">true</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro>",
                            "representation":"storage"}}}' 
     'https://localhost:8080/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new page with macro attachment:

```html
curl -s -u user:pasw -X POST 
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json'
 '-d{"type":"page","ancestors":[{"id":**<parent ID>**}], 
     "title":"New page with macro attach","space":{"key":"TST"}, 
     "body":{"storage":{"value":"<p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"attachments\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"old\">false</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"sortBy\">name</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p>","representation":"storage"}}}' 
 'https://localhost:8080/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic'
```

Insert into page marco attachment:

```html
curl -s -u user:pasw -X PUT 
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 '-d{"version":{"number":**"2"**},
     "title":"Test page for insert macro",
     "type":"page",
     "body":{"storage":{"value":"<p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"attachments\" ac:schema-version=\"1\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"old\">false</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"sortBy\">name</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p>","representation":"storage"}}}' 
 https://localhost:8080/rest/api/content/**<cuurent page ID>**
```